# How to format x-axis time-series tick marks with missing dates

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I format the x-axis so that the spacing between periods is "to scale". As in, the distance between 10yr and 30yr should be much larger than the distance between 1yr and 2yr.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Quandl as ql

yield_ = ql.get("USTREASURY/YIELD")
today = yield_.iloc[-1,:]
month_ago = yield_.iloc[-1000,:]
df = pd.concat([today, month_ago], axis=1)
df.columns = ['today', 'month_ago']
df.plot(style={'today': 'ro-', 'month_ago': 'bx--'},title='Treasury Yield Curve, %');

plt.show()
```

I want my chart to look like this...[image: Yield Curve Chart]

Answer (score 1):

I think doing this while staying purely within Pandas might be tricky. You first need to create a new matplotlib figure and axe. The following might not work exactly but will give you a good idea.

```
df['years']=[1/12.,0.25,0.5,1,2,3,5,7,10,20,30]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
df.plot(x='years',y='today',ax=ax,kind='scatter')
df.plot(x='years',y='month_ago',ax=ax,kind='scatter')
plt.show()
```

If you want your axe labels to look like your chart you'll also need to set the lower and upper limit of your axis so they look good and then do something like:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(list(df.index))
```

Comment: Is there a better way than Pandas?

Comment: @Brian, I just meant you actually need to play around with figure / axes within matplotlib instead of just pandas calls.